# System.Text.Json.Deserialize can still not handle TimeSpan in .NET Core 5?

Tags: c#, json, .net, timespan, .net-5

I have the following TimeSpan JSON string genereated from `JsonSerilizer.Serialize<TimeSpan>(MyTymeSpan)`; :

> jsonString= {"Ticks":1770400500000,"Days":2,"Hours":1,"Milliseconds":50,"Minutes":10,"Seconds":40,"TotalDays":2.0490746527777777,"TotalHours":49.177791666666664,"TotalMilliseconds":177040050,"TotalMinutes":2950.6675,"TotalSeconds":177040.05}

When executing this :

```
JsonSerializer.Deserialize<T>(jsonString);
```

I get a TimeSpan that is 0?

Some articles says that this should be fixed in .NET Core 5 so why do I get 0?

Regards

Comment: Just as a comment to your last line, this feature didn't make the cut for .Net5. It is currently planned for .Net6.

Comment: The sad truth is that it is not supported yet ([one of the realted github issue](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/29932)). [The promise is that .NET 6](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/24601) will handle it correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

System.Text.Json.Deserialize will not handle TimeSpan in Core 5 and because of my environment it was better to just revert back to Newtonsofts version for now. But from what I understand the .NET version is a lot faster so as soon as it can handle the types correctly it might be worth migrating.

Answer (score 0):

No, not out of the box. In fact that mess you're getting when serializing is broken because it stores the same value multiple times (the `Total*` values), and useless information at the beginning.

You have two options:

1. Serialize and deserialize the `Ticks` property. That is enough to build a `TimeSpan` in a cross-platform way. Don't use the `Total*` properties because they lose information due to resolution, `Ticks` is a raw 64-bit integer that fully represents how much resolution the .Net specs give the `TimeSpan` type, and it will not change.
2. Write a custom JsonConverter that serializes the `Ticks` property for `TimeSpan`. A bit more code to set up, but then you can just use `TimeSpan` directly in your class.

Comment: 1. I tried sending in a JSON string from my unittest with ticks("1770400500000") but that would not convert to TimeSpan.

2. I found samples of custom Json converter but all of them needs to be set during ServiceStartup and when running unittest there is none. I tried to set it as a option for the JSONSerializer but during deserializing it throws exception from inside the converter.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "would not convert to TimeSpan", it's an integer, not a TimeSpan. To construct a TimeSpan, you'd use `TimeSpan.FromTicks(ticks)`. As to unit tests, that's what dependency injection is for, to set up a unit test context separate from your main application. And as to the last part, "threw an exception" says nothing. Be an actual programmer and use your debugger to see what the exception says, where it throws and how to fix it.